# Why does it darken when you press space bar on a radio button option?

Tags: css

When tapping the spacebar on an option you'll see it darken.  You can "darken" multiple options until you arrow key back through the options.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio

Comment: can't reproduce on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing form field "focus" occurring. It's the same thing that happens when you select a text field before entering text. By default, browsers add a ring or glow to the element. This is a usability thing to help people understand which elements are currently being interacted with.

However, I'm unable to focus multiple radio buttons in your example (Chrome 70 Mac OS). Typically radio buttons don't allow multiple select so you may be seeing something browser specific.

Comment: Could you try this?  Tab focus to the first radio control.  Press the spacebar.  Press arrow key down to jump to next option.  Press spacebar.  Press arrow key down again.  Do you notice the two options above having a slightly darker shade?  I'm also on Chrome 70 on Mac OS, but on 10.13.4.